# Word definition request

Tags: word-choice

I am searching for a word that describes a person who complains about people who complain. I have tried numerous synonym blogs, but cannot find anything satisfactory.

Comment: Can you provide a sentence where you would use it?

Comment: I don't think such a word exists, but I feel a need for it, too. Can I try to invent some? Or is this forbidden by the rules?

Comment: You could call them a hypocrite.

Comment: But if you invent such a word, user626528, what will we call people who complain about such souls?

Comment: @user626528 not as an answer, but I usually will do so in a comment, for example: metacomplainer, comcomplainer.

Comment: @JeffSahol, Ok. I'd call them meta-whiners.

Comment: Or "derivative whiners". Does this sound understandable enough?

Comment: "kvetcher-kvetcher"

Comment: @user626528 "whine connoisseur"...or, by extension, "oenophobic"

Comment: Good question: Jim.

Answer (score 1):

Truly the behavior you describe is most often designated by the adjective “hypocritical,” while the actor noun is, of course, a "hypocrite." If the term is too harsh-sounding, you can add a modifying adverb ie, “unconsciously, unintentionally, or inadvertently hypocritical,” or an adjectival modifier with the noun, hypocrite. And, it is well worth noting, we all have our blind-spots and are, to a greater or lesser degree, possessed of this same character flaw. Much like the person you seek to describe, what we find disagreeable in another, we are often blind to in ourselves.

> **Hypocrite** *noun*
>
> **1**. a person who pretends to have virtues, moral or religious beliefs, principles, etc., that he or she does not actually possess, especially a person whose actions belie stated beliefs.
>
> **2**. a person who feigns some desirable or publicly approved attitude, especially one whose private life, opinions, or statements belie his or her public statements. See, Thesaurus.com [**LINK**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hypocrite)

Or, the less common designation, a "dissimulator," or one who "dissimulates"

> **Dissimulate** *verb* (used with object), dissimulated, dissimulating.
>
> **1**. to disguise or conceal under a false appearance; dissemble: 
>   "to dissimulate one's true feelings about a rival."
>   verb (used without object), dissimulated, dissimulating.
>
> **2**. to conceal one's true motives, thoughts, etc., by some pretense; speak or act hypocritically. See, Thesaurus.com [**LINK**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dissimulator)

Comment: These words are very general, not specific to complaining about complaining.

Comment: @Barmar - no such English word exists.

Answer (score 0):

If the complainers are continually complaining then they could be described as whingers; and since you disapprove of such behaviour then you are an anti-whinger. If you want to declaim your disapproval then you could be a whinge-denouncer or a whinge-decrier or a whinge-deplorer or a whinge-censor ...